# ubuntu 20.04 brute force

Tags: security, ssh, ubuntu-20.04

I am using ubuntu 20.04. When I looked at the auth.log records, I saw that there were many attempts. What security measures can be taken here.

I don't have any previous experience in this field. Security issues are very new to me. I am open to anything you suggest.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few recommendations assuming that you are talking about SSH:

1. Disable login access to `root`: [disable-root-login](https://linux-audit.com/audit-and-harden-your-ssh-configuration/#disable-root-login)
2. Enable public key authentication and disable password based auth: [public-key-authentication](https://linux-audit.com/audit-and-harden-your-ssh-configuration/#public-key-authentication)
3. Add IP whitelisting, using a firewall such as `ufw` to ensure people can only access from your IP address

Comment: Thank you very much Nick. I did what you said and everything is better already :)